# strcat (s1, s2) continues to apparent to my temp variable array

Tags: c, arrays

Newbie to programming (school) and I'm a little confused on what/why this is happening.

I have a loop that is iterating over an array of elements, for each element I am taking the integer of the array, converting it to a char using the function getelementsymbol, and using strcat to append to my temp array.  The problem I am having is that the elements of my temp array contain the residual of the element proceeding it.  This is the snippet of my code.  The output I receive is this:

word1

word1word2

word1word2word3

```
char* elementsBuildWord(const int symbols[], int nbSymbols){
/*  ROLE            takes a list of elements' atomic numbers and allocate a new string made
                    of the symbols of each of these elements
PARAMETERS      symbols     an array of nbSymbols int which each represent the atomic number
                                of an element
                    nbSymbols   symbols array's size
RETURN VALUE    NULL    if the array is of size <= 0
                            or if one of the symbols is not found by our getElementSymbol function
                    other   the address of a newly allocated string representing the    concatenation
                            of the names of all symbols
 */
    char s1[MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH];
    int y;
    char *s2;
    size_t i;

    for (i = 0; i < nbSymbols; i++){
        y = symbols[i];
        s2 = getElementSymbol(y);
        strcat(s1, s2);         
    }
    printf("%s ", s1);
}
```

Comment: While your code contains some serious issues, the output you provided so far looks OK. Why do you think it is wrong? `strcat` appends a new string to the end of the existing string. This is exactly what you see in your output. So, what is the problem?

Comment: Before calling `strcat` you should make sure there is enough room in `s1`.

Comment: Perhaps look up the word "append" in the dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, your `s1` is not initialized. `strcat` function append a new string to an existing string. This means that your `s1` has to be a *string* from the very beginning. An uninitialized char array is not a string. A good idea would be to declare your `s1` as

```
char s1[MAX_GENERATED_WORD_LENGTH] = { 0 };
```

or at least do

```
s1[0] = '\0';
```

before starting your cycle.

Secondly, your `getElementSymbol` function returns a `char *` pointer. Where does that pointer point to? Who manages the memory it points to? This is non-obvious from your code. It is possible that the function returns an invalid pointer (like a pointer to a local buffer), which is why might see various anomalies. There's no way to say without seeing how it is implemented.

Comment: AndreyT, I will try that.  I forgot that the array needs to be initialized if am to use strcat.  Thank you!

Comment: Bingo!  Thank you so much.  Yeah, my code definitely can be cleaned up, but for now I need get the expected results first so sorry for the poor code.  My output needed each word that is constructed in it's own element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

`strcat` is supposed to append to a string. use `strcpy` if you want to overwrite the existing string.  You could also use `s1[0] = '\0';` before `strcat` to "blank" the string if you really want to, but looks like you really want `strcpy`.

From the snippet above it's not even clear why you need `s1` - you could just print `s2`...

Comment: Also note that "cat" in strcat means concatenate.

Comment: The instructions provided says I am to concatenate in order to build the word.  So I am using strcat to append the what getelementsymbol returns.  I tried your idea to print s2, but the results are not what I am looking. Thank you though.  I believe you and AndreyT have helped by reminding that my temp array (s1) needs to be initialized.  I think that may be error.